# How to display array item in Angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular

I am a newbie in Angular, I create an array but I have problem to display it.

When I display the array item it is blank.

write.component.html:

```
    <div class="data">
        <li> Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Please enter Name" ></li>
        <li> Age:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="age" placeholder="Please enter Age" class="age"></li>
        <li>College:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="college" placeholder="Please enter College" ></li>
        </div>

    <h2>Student</h2>
    <ul class="details">
      <li>
        <span class="badge" *ngFor="let student of students">  // display array item
          {{student.name}}{{student.age}}{{student.college}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

.ts

```
export class WriteComponent implements OnInit {
  name : string;
  age : number;
  college : string;

students : Array<any>; // declare array

}
```

write-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";


@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  private students = new Array<any>( //array details
    {
      name:"dwq",
      age:12,
      college:"2321"
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: did you inject the service ?

Comment: check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-orrsud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the service you have to inject that service to your component like this

```
  constructor(private homeServ:HomeService) {  }
```

then the service will be avilable in the componnet you can get the data

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.students = this.homeServ.getStudents();
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-orrsud)

> you can remove the injectable decorator from the service if the service has no dependency

read more about angular services  [her](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)